# how to use matlab logical functions with arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am using Matlab.

I compare a zero array A with some other arrays (e.g. `[1 1 0 0]`)

I write the following code:

```
A=[0 0 0 0];

if (A~=[1 1 0 0] & A~=[1 0 1 0] & A~=[1 1 0 1])
    x=1;
else
    x=0;
end
```

I expected to see that `x=1` but the answer i get is `x=0`

what do i wrong ?

Comment: why do you expect to see `x=1`?

Answer (score 1):

`~=` and `&` are element wise operators, so the expression

```
A~=[1 1 0 0] & A~=[1 0 1 0] & A~=[1 1 0 1]
```

where `A = [0 0 0 0]` produces the vector output:

```
[1 0 0 0]
```

An `if` statement evaluated on a vector does an implicit [all](http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2014/02/10/understand-if-statement-behavior-on-vectors/), which in that case evaluates to `false`.

It's not exactly clear what you want, but if you want to make sure the vector `A` is not equal to any of `[1 1 0 0]`, `[1 0 1 0]` or `[1 1 0 1]` then you need to do this:

```
x = ~isequal(A, [1 1 0 0]) && ~isequal(A, [1 0 1 0]) && ~isequal(A, [1 1 0 1])
```

Answer (score 1):

The matlab equality operators compares array element-wise and returns true/false (logical 1/0) for each element. So when you have `A = [1 1 0 0], B = [1 0 1 0]` and you check for `A == B`, you don't get 'false' but instead you get [1 0 0 1].

If you want to check if the whole vectors A and B are equal you need to check if the condition 
`all(A==B)`is true or not

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to find exact match, so for that you may use this -

```
%%// If *ANY* of the element-wise comparisons are not-true, give me 1,
%%// otherwise give me 0. Thus, in other words, I am looking to find the 
%%// exact match (element-wise) only, otherwise give me 1 as x.
if any(A~=[1 1 0 0] & A~=[1 0 1 0] & A~=[1 1 0 1]) 
    x=1;
else
    x=0;
end
```

Another way to put it would be -

```
%%// *ALL* elementwise comparisons must be satisfied, to give x as 0, 
%%// otherwise give x as 1.
if all(A==[1 1 0 0] & A==[1 0 1 0] & A==[1 1 0 1]) 
    x=0;
else
    x=1;
end
```

Get more info about [`any`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/any.html) and [`all`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/all.html), that are used here.